# Event Dispacher in Java

Tags: java, events, event-handling

I need to to make for school a simple "strategy game simulator". To do this I need to make an Event Dispatcher (event loop) that will send the event to the registered parties. For example, I have resources on the map. One event is "resource at location 1 depleted". And one "player" is interested on that event. 
How would I create the dispatcher (and register one player for one particular event). Also, how does the dispatcher check for the event? Does it simply do something like `if(resourceLocation1.getNoResource()==0) trigerEvent();` or is there some other, more elegant way.

I worked with event listeners (mostly in ActionScrip3) but never made a custom event and a custom event dispatcher. Any help is appreciated, including some links to some tutorials or sample codes.

If I am not clear what I am searching for please let me know and I will try to explain it better

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a difference between the Observer pattern and an event dispatcher?

Comment: Do you need to have the event loop and the listeners in different threads?

Comment: @toto2 Observer + Mediator patterns = EventDispatcher pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EventDispatcher` does not need to check every possible condition and notify all possible listeners.  Just notify listeners registered for a certain type of event.

Register `Player` to be notified depending on the game event

```
eventDispatcher.register(player, Events.RESOURCE_DEPLETION_EVENT);
```

Then your `Resource` would supply an event when resources reached `0`

```
class Resource {
    public void deplete(int amount) {
         this.amount -= amount;
         if (this.amount <= 0)
             eventDispatcher.notify(this, Events.RESOURCE_DEPLETION_EVENT);
    }
 }
```

Otherwise you are going to end up with a massive logic-containing event loop that eats up performance and will be difficult to debug.

Comment: BTW if you accept answers that are helpful you will be more likely to get answered in the future...

Answer (score 1):

Java has a built-in thread-safe [Observer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) pattern you can use.

To write your own you would have `Player` implement a `ResourceDepeletionListener` interface and add it to an array of listeners in your `Resource` class.  When the resources reach zero they call `resourcesDepleted()` on all `ResourceDepeletionListener` objects.

Comment: An Observer pattern would work but the requirement of the task is to make an Event Dispatcher, event sources and event consumers.

Answer (score 1):

What about implementing an [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)?

For instance, you can have a `ResourceObserver`, which registers a particular `Resource` as an observable. From there, you can have `Player` objects register as observers to your `ResourceObserver`. A map object will hold all the resources. In your event loop, you will have something like:

```
...
Map.updateResources();
...
```

So for instance, when you call `updateResources`, all the map resources will check if they have been depleted. If a resource has been depeleted, it will notify it's `ResourceObserver`, which will in turn notify all registered players for that resource.

Comment: An Observer pattern would work but the requirement of the task is to make an Event Dispatcher, event sources and event consumers.